# How can I check if a file can be created or truncated/overwritten in bash?

Tags: bash, files, error-handling

The user calls my script with a file path that will be either be created or overwritten at some point in the script, like `foo.sh file.txt` or `foo.sh dir/file.txt`.

The create-or-overwrite behavior is much like the requirements for putting the file on the right side of the `>` output redirect operator, or passing it as an argument to `tee` (in fact, passing it as an argument to `tee` is exactly what I'm doing).

Before I get into the guts of the script, I want to make a reasonable check if the file *can* be created/overwritten, but not actually create it. This check doesn't have to be perfect, and yes I realize that the situation can change between the check and the point where the file is actually written - but here I'm OK with a *best effort* type solution so I can bail out early in the case that the file path is invalid.

Examples of reasons the file couldn't created:

- the file contains a directory component, like `dir/file.txt` but the directory `dir` doesn't exist
- the user doens't have write permissions in the specified directory (or the CWD if no directory was specified

Yes, I realize that checking permissions "up front" is not *The UNIX Way™*, rather I should just try the operation and ask forgiveness later. In my particular script however, this leads to a bad user experience and I can't change the responsible component.

Comment: Will the argument always be based on the current directory or could the user specify a full path?

Comment: @Jesse_b - I suppose the user could specify an absolute path like `/foo/bar/file.txt`. Basically I pass the path to `tee` like `tee $OUT_FILE` where `OUT_FILE` is passed on the command line. That should "just work" with both absolute and relative paths, right?

Comment: @BeeOnRope, no you'd need `tee -- "$OUT_FILE"` at least. What if the file already exists or exists but is not a regular file (directory, symlink, fifo)?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - well I am using `tee "${OUT_FILE}.tmp"`. If the file already exists, `tee` overwrites, which is the desired behavior in this case. If it's a directory, `tee` will fail (I think). symlink I'm not 100% sure?

Answer (score 13):

The obvious test would be:

```
if touch /path/to/file; then
    : it can be created
fi
```

But it does actually create the file if it's not already there.  We could clean up after ourselves:

```
if touch /path/to/file; then
    rm /path/to/file
fi
```

But this would remove a file that already existed, which you probably don't want.

We do, however, have a way around this:

```
if mkdir /path/to/file; then
    rmdir /path/to/file
fi
```

You can't have a directory with the same name as another object in that directory.  I can't think of a situation in which you'd be able to create a directory but not create a file.  After this test, your script would be free to create a conventional `/path/to/file` and do whatever it pleases with it.

Comment: That very neatly handles so many issues! A code comment explaining & justifying that unusual solution might well exceed the length of your answer. :-)

Comment: I also have used `if mkdir /var/run/lockdir` as a locking test.  This is atomic, while `if ! [[ -f /var/run/lockfile ]]; then touch /var/run/lockfile` has a small slice of time in between the test and `touch` where another instance of the script in question can start.

Answer (score 8):

From what I'm gathering, you want to check that when using

```
tee -- "$OUT_FILE"
```

(note the `--` or it wouldn't work for file names that start with -), `tee` would succeed to open the file for writing.

That is that:

- the length of the file path doesn't exceed the PATH_MAX limit
- the file exists (after symlink resolution) and is not of type *directory* and you have write permission to it.
- if the file doesn't exist, the dirname of the file exists (after symlink resolution) as a directory and you have write and search permission to it and the filename length doesn't exceed the NAME_MAX limit of the filesystem that directory resides in.
- or the file is a symlink that points to a file that doesn't exist and is not a symlink loop but meets the criteria just above

We'll ignore for now filesystems like vfat, ntfs or hfsplus that have limitations on what byte values file names may contain, disk quota, process limit, selinux, apparmor or other security mechanism in the way, full filesystem, no inode left, device files that can't be opened that way for a reason or another, files that are executables currently mapped in some process address space all of which could also affect the ability to open or create the file.

With `zsh`:

```
zmodload zsh/system
tee_would_likely_succeed() {
  local file=$1 ERRNO=0 LC_ALL=C
  if [ -d "$file" ]; then
    return 1 # directory
  elif [ -w "$file" ]; then
    return 0 # writable non-directory
  elif [ -e "$file" ]; then
    return 1 # exists, non-writable
  elif [ "$errnos[ERRNO]" != ENOENT ]; then
    return 1 # only ENOENT error can be recovered
  else
    local dir=$file:P:h base=$file:t
    [ -d "$dir" ] &&    # directory
      [ -w "$dir" ] &&  # writable
      [ -x "$dir" ] &&  # and searchable
      (($#base <= $(getconf -- NAME_MAX "$dir")))
    return
  fi
}
```

In `bash` or any Bourne-like shell, just replace the

```
zmodload zsh/system
tee_would_likely_succeed() {
  <zsh-code>
}
```

with:

```
tee_would_likely_succeed() {
  zsh -s -- "$@" << 'EOF'
  zmodload zsh/system
  <zsh-code>
EOF
}
```

The `zsh`-specific features here are `$ERRNO` (which exposes the error code of the last system call) and `$errnos[]` associative array to translate to the corresponding standard C macro names. And the `$var:h` (from csh) and `$var:P` (needs zsh 5.3 or above).

bash doesn't have equivalent features yet.

`$file:h` can be replaced with `dir=$(dirname -- "$file"; echo .); dir=${dir%??}`, or with GNU `dirname`: `IFS= read -rd '' dir < <(dirname -z -- "$file")`.

For `$errnos[ERRNO] == ENOENT`, an approach could be to run `ls -Ld` on the file and check whether the error message corresponds to the ENOENT error. Doing that reliably and portably is tricky though.

One approach could be:

```
msg_for_ENOENT=$(LC_ALL=C ls -d -- '/no such file' 2>&1)
msg_for_ENOENT=${msg_for_ENOENT##*:}
```

(assuming that the error message *ends* with the `syserror()` translation of `ENOENT` and that that translation doesn't include a `:`) and then, instead of `[ -e "$file" ]`, do:

```
err=$(ls -Ld -- "$file" 2>&1)
```

And check for a ENOENT error with

```
case $err in
  (*:"$msg_for_ENOENT") ...
esac
```

The `$file:P` part is the trickiest to achieve in `bash`, especially on FreeBSD.

FreeBSD does have a `realpath` command and a `readlink` command that accepts a `-f` option, but they can't be used in the cases where the file is a symlink that doesn't resolve. That's the same with `perl`'s `Cwd::realpath()`.

`python`'s `os.path.realpath()` does appear to work similarly to `zsh` `$file:P`, so assuming that at least one version of `python` is installed and that there is a `python` command that refers to one of them (which is not a given on FreeBSD), you could do:

```
dir=$(python -c '
import os, sys
print(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[1]) + ".")' "$dir") || return
dir=${dir%.}
```

But then, you might as well do the whole thing in `python`.

Or you could decide not to handle all those corner cases.

Comment: Yes, you understood my intent correctly. In fact, the original question was unclear: I originally spoke about _creating_ the file, but actually I am using it with `tee` so the requirement is really that the file can be created _if_ it doesn't exist, or can be truncated to zero and overwritten if it does (or however else `tee` handles that).

Comment: Looks like your last edit wiped the formatting

Comment: Thanks, @​bishop, @D.BenKnoble, see edit.

Comment: Your Bash example requires that zsh is installed. If so, just use zsh directly.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson, well yes, a shell  is a tool to invoke programs, and every program that you invoke in your script has to be installed for your script to work, that goes without saying. macOS comes with both bash and zsh installed by default. FreeBSD comes with neither. The OP may have a good reason for wanting to do that in bash, maybe it's something they want to add to an already written bash script.

Comment: Do you also insist on giving C# answers to every question about C++? This is ridiculous.

Comment: @pipe, again, a shell is a command interpreter. You'll see that many shell code excerpts  written here invoke interpreters of other languages like `perl`, `awk`, `sed` or `python` (or even `sh`, `bash`...). Shell scripting is about using the best command for the task. Here even `perl` doesn't have an equivalent of `zsh`'s `$var:P` (its `Cwd::realpath` behaves like BSD `realpath` or `readlink -f` while you'd want it to behave like GNU `readlink -f` or `python`'s `os.path.realpath()`)

Comment: @pipe It's actually pretty common to have shell scripts that are wrappers for other commands/interpreters. A well known example is the Red Hat's `service` command, which basically [translates System V init syntax to systemd syntax](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Services#tabl-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Services-systemctl) to avoid breaking compatibility with legacy scripts.

Answer (score 6):

One option you might want to consider is *creating* the file early on but only populating it later in your script. You can use the `exec` command to open the file in a file descriptor (such as 3, 4, etc.) and then later use a redirection to a file descriptor (`>&3`, etc.) to write contents to that file.

Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Open the file for read/write, so it doesn't get
# truncated just yet (to preserve the contents in
# case the initial checks fail.)
exec 3<>dir/file.txt || {
    echo "Error creating dir/file.txt" >&2
    exit 1
}

# Long checks here...
check_ok || {
    echo "Failed checks" >&2
    # cleanup file before bailing out
    rm -f dir/file.txt
    exit 1
}

# We're ready to write, first truncate the file.
# Use "truncate(1)" from coreutils, and pass it
# /dev/fd/3 so the file doesn't need to be reopened.
truncate -s 0 /dev/fd/3

# Now populate the file, use a redirection to write
# to the previously opened file descriptor.
populate_contents >&3
```

You can also use a `trap` to clean up the file on error, that's a common practice.

This way, you get a *real* check for permissions that you'll be able to create the file, while at the same time being able to perform it early enough that if that fails you haven't spent time waiting for the long checks.

---

**UPDATED:** In order to avoid clobbering the file in case the checks fail, use bash's [`fd<>file` redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Opening-File-Descriptors-for-Reading-and-Writing) which does not truncate the file right away. (We don't care about reading from the file, this is just a workaround so we don't truncate it. Appending with `>>` would probably just work too, but I tend to find this one a bit more elegant, keeping the O_APPEND flag out of the picture.)

When we're ready to replace the contents, we need to truncate the file first (otherwise if we're writing fewer bytes than there were in the file before, the trailing bytes would stay there.) We can use the [truncate(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/truncate) command from coreutils for that purpose, and we can pass it the open file descriptor we have (using the `/dev/fd/3` pseudo-file) so it doesn't need to reopen the file. (Again, technically something simpler like `: >dir/file.txt` would probably work, but not having to reopen the file is a more elegant solution.)

Comment: I had considered this, but the problem is that if another innocent error occurs somewhere between when I create the file and the point some time later where I would write to it, the user will probably be upset to find out that the specified file was overwritten.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting... I had this idea of using `set -o noclobber`, in which case it would fail if the file already existed... But then I don't think it's possible to differentiate failure due to permissions (abort script) from failure due to file already existing (in which case you'd like to proceed and later overwrite the file.) If this was C or Python, etc., it's just a matter of opening the file with O_EXCL and looking for error EEXIST (permissions are fine, but file already exists) from EACCES (permission denied)... But not sure that can be done in bash...

Comment: @BeeOnRope Updated the answer, now using `3<>file` redirection so the file doesn't get clobbered when opened, and using the truncate(1) command to truncate it right as we're about to replace its contents. I hope you like that solution!

Comment: @BeeOnRope another option that won't clobber the file is to try to append *nothing* to it: `echo -n >>file` or `true >> file`. Of course, ext4 has append-only files, but you could live with that false positive.

Comment: @BeeOnRope If you need to preserve either (a) the existing file or (b) the (complete) new file, that's a different question than you have asked. A good answer to it is to move the existing file to a new name (e.g. `my-file.txt.backup`) before creating the new one. Another solution is to write the new file to a temporary file in the same folder, and then copy it over the old file after the rest of the script succeeds --- if that last operation failed, the user could manually fix the issue without losing his or her progress.

Comment: @jpaugh - yes, well there are two things: what I asked, and what I am trying to do at a higher level. People always like knowing more about the second part, so basically what I'm doing is in a script that takes a file, doing a bunch of work which may fail (or, more likely, be cancelled by a bored user typing `^c`), which goes to a temporary file (I don't expect this file to exist and I don't both making checks about it). As the _last_ step, I do a final processing step using `grep` which overwrites the user-specified file (in a pipeline it is passed as an argument to `tee`).

Comment: Whew... so what I'd like is for the script to bail out at the start if that last step will fail! It sucks to wait an hour only to see that there was a typo in the file name and you lost the results. About overwriting versus create: I just want it to check that what `tee` does will work: which is create if it doesn't exist, or overwrite otherwise. The overwrite part is relevant because several people suggested solutions that would clobber the original file as part of the check, which isn't what I want because then even if you cancel the job or it fails, the output file is clobbered!

Comment: The file should contain its original contents in that case. You are right that writing things into a temporary file (where?) and then doing a rename/replace at the end can help, since at least you don't lose all your work, it's still sitting there in the temporary file.

Comment: @BeeOnRope If you go for the "atomic replace" route (which is a good one!) then typically you'll want to write the temporary file in the same directory as the final file (they need to be in the same filesystem for rename(2) to succeed) and use a unique name (so if there are two instances of the script running, they won't clobber each other's temporary files.) Opening a temporary file for writing in the same directory is usually a good indication you'll be able to rename it later (well, except if the final target exists and is a directory), so to some extent it also addresses your question.

Comment: Yes, I am currently using "same directory" (since as above, I do use a temporary file for all but the last step), but then this causes the same type of problem as the original question: if the specified file has a path component, then the temporary file creation may fail if the path component is bad, and this may happen at some much later point in the script. So I kind of like the original question/approach, which is validating the paths up front: this could be _combined_ with the atomic rename approach which itself has a lot of other advantages.

Comment: You can create the temporary file in the same directory as the final target at the start of the script, and keep it open throughout, just writing to it later on and renaming it when finished. This should cover most checks for being able to write to the final file, perhaps with the exception of when the final file is a directory, in which case the rename(2) operation will fail... Hmmm, perhaps there's more to it, based on file permissions/ownership of the target file, but I think it's for the most part about the directory. One advantage is if final rename fails, you can keep tmpfile and notify.

Comment: @BeeOnRope Hi! You should definitely include the details you mention above in your original question. Few will notice this comment thread, and the font is much harder to read.

Comment: @jpaugh - I'm quite reluctant to do that. It would inevitably lead to answers trying to solve my higher level problem, which might admit solutions that have nothing to do with the question "How can I check...". Regardless of what my high level problem is, I think this question stands alone as something you might reasonably want to do. It would be unfair to people who are answering that specific question if I changed it to "solve this specific issue I'm having with my script". I included those details here because I was asked, but I don't want to put change the primary question.

Answer (score 4):

I think DopeGhoti's solution is better but this should also work:

```
file=$1
if [[ "${file:0:1}" == '/' ]]; then
    dir=${file%/*}
elif [[ "$file" =~ .*/.* ]]; then
    dir="$(PWD)/${file%/*}"
else
    dir=$(PWD)
fi

if [[ -w "$dir" ]]; then
    echo "writable"
    #do stuff with writable file
else
    echo "not writable"
    #do stuff without writable file
fi
```

The first if construct checks if the argument is a full path (starts with `/`) and sets the `dir` variable to the directory path up to the last `/`.  Otherwise if the argument does not start with a `/` but does contain a `/` (specifying a sub directory) it will set `dir` to the present working directory + the sub directory path.  Otherwise it assumes the present working directory.  It then checks if that directory is writable.

Answer (score 4):

What about using normal `test` command like outlined below?

```
FILE=$1

DIR=$(dirname $FILE) # $DIR now contains '.' for file names only, 'foo' for 'foo/bar'

if [ -d $DIR ] ; then
  echo "base directory $DIR for file exists"
  if [ -e $FILE ] ; then
    if [ -w $FILE ] ; then
      echo "file exists, is writeable"
    else
      echo "file exists, NOT writeable"
    fi
  elif [ -w $DIR ] ; then
    echo "directory is writeable"
  else
    echo "directory is NOT writeable"
  fi
else
  echo "can NOT create file in non-existent directory $DIR "
fi
```

Comment: I almost duplicated this answer!  Nice introduction, but you might mention `man test`, and that `[ ]` is equivalent to test (not common knowledge anymore). Here is a the one-liner i was about to use in my inferior answer, to cover the exact case, for posterity:
`if [ -w $1] && [ ! -d $1 ] ; then echo "do stuff";  fi`

Answer (score 4):

You mentioned user experience was driving your question. I'll answer from a UX angle, since you've got good answers on the technical side.

Rather than performing the check up-front, how about writing the results into a *temporary file* then at the very end, placing the results into the user's desired file? Like:

```
userfile=${1:?Where would you like the file written?}
tmpfile=$(mktemp)

# ... all the complicated stuff, writing into "${tmpfile}"

# fill user's file, keeping existing permissions or creating anew
# while respecting umask
cat "${tmpfile}" > "${userfile}"
if [ 0 -eq $? ]; then
    rm "${tmpfile}"
else
    echo "Couldn't write results into ${userfile}." >&2
    echo "Results available in ${tmpfile}." >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

The good with this approach: it produces the desired operation in the normal happy path scenario, side-steps the test-and-set atomicity issue, preserves permissions of the target file while creating if necessary, and is dead simple to implement.

Note: had we used `mv`, we'd be keeping the permissions of the temporary file -- we don't want that, I think: we want to keep the permissions as set on the target file.

Now, the bad: it requires twice the space (`cat .. >` construct), forces the user to do some manual work if the target file wasn't writable at the time it needed to be, and leaves the temporary file laying around (which might have security or maintenance issues).

Comment: In fact, this is more or less what I'm doing now. I write most of the results to a temporary file and then at the end do the final processing step and write the results to the final file. The problem is I want to bail out early (at the start of the script) if that final step is likely to fail. The script may run unattended for minutes or hours, so you really want to know up front that it is doomed to fail!

Comment: Sure, but there are so many ways this could fail: disk could fill, upstream directory could be removed, permissions could change, target file might be used for some other important stuff and the user forgot he assigned that same file to be destroyed by this operation. If we talk about this from a pure UX perspective, then perhaps the right thing to do is treat it like a job submission: at the end, when you know it worked correctly to completion, just tell the user where the resulting content resides and offer a _suggested_ command for them to move it themselves.

Comment: In theory, yes there are infinite ways this could fail. In practice, the overwhelming majority of the time this fails is because the path provided is not valid. I can't reasonably prevent some rogue user from concurrently modifying the FS to break the job in the middle of the operation, but I certainly can check the #1 failure cause of an invalid or not writable path.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:**

```
: >> "${userfile}"
```

Unlike `<> "${userfile}"` or `touch "${userfile}"`, this will not make any spurious modifications to the file's timestamps and will also work with write-only files.

---

From the OP:

> I want to make a reasonable check if the file can be created/overwritten, but not actually create it.

And from your comment to [my answer from a UX perspective](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/480789/50240):

> The overwhelming majority of the time this fails is because the path provided is not valid. I can't reasonably prevent some rogue user some concurrently modifying the FS to break the job in the middle of the operation, but I certainly can check the #1 failure cause of an invalid or not writable path.

The only reliable test is to [`open(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) the file, because only that resolves every question about the writeability: path, ownership, filesystem, network, security context, etc. Any other test will address some part of writeability, but not others. If you want a subset of tests, you'll ultimately have to choose what's important to you.

But here's another thought. From what I understand:

1. the content creation process is long-running, and
2. the target file should be left in a consistent state.

You're wanting to do this pre-check because of #1, and you don't want to fiddle with an existing file because of #2. So why don't you just ask the shell to open the file for append, but don't actually append anything?

```
$ tree -ps
.
├── [dr-x------        4096]  dir_r
├── [drwx------        4096]  dir_w
├── [-r--------           0]  file_r
└── [-rw-------           0]  file_w

$ for p in file_r dir_r/foo file_w dir_w/foo; do : >> $p; done
-bash: file_r: Permission denied
-bash: dir_r/foo: Permission denied

$ tree -ps
.
├── [dr-x------        4096]  dir_r
├── [drwx------        4096]  dir_w
│   └── [-rw-rw-r--           0]  foo
├── [-r--------           0]  file_r
└── [-rw-------           0]  file_w
```

Under the hood, this resolves the writeability question exactly as wanted:

```
open("dir_w/foo", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0666) = 3
```

but without modifying the file's contents or metadata. Now, yes, this approach:

- doesn't tell you if the file is append only, which might be a problem when you go about updating it at the end of your content creation. You can detect this, to a degree, with `lsattr` and react accordingly.
- creates a file that didn't previously exist, if such is the case: mitigate this with a selective `rm`.

While I contend (in my other answer) that the *most user-friendly* approach is to create a temporary file the user has to move, I think this is the *least user-hostile* approach to fully vet their input.